# Getting RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid on osx sed

Tags: shell, debian, sed, osx

I'm copy a sed script form Ubuntu debian to osx but getting

RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

What is wrong?

```
$ . sed_shorter_version_user_extensions_to_ruby.sh
sed: 22: "
### DELETE whole lines ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
Inspecting 1 file...
...
```

The script is:
(I left the line numbers in in case the 22 means line 22).

```
  1 sed '
  2 ### DELETE whole lines
  3 /\/\//d
  4 /^$/d
  5 ### CHANGE large chunks
  6 s/^storedVars\["/  def /
  7 s/SAD/sad/
  8 s/HAPPY/happy/
  9 s/"\][[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/\
 10     /
 11 s/;/\
 12   end\
 13 /
 14 ### CHANGE small chunks
 15 s/"css=/"/
 16 s/"link=/"/
 17 s/"label=/"/
 18 ### CHANGE specific lines
 19 ### Scoped corrections for clarity
 20 /def insurance_expiration/ {
 21   /expiration_month/ {
 22     s/"value=.*\+1)/"(Date.new + 1.month).strftime(%B)"/
 23   }
 24   /expiration_year/ {
 25     s/"value=.*FullYear())/"(Date.new + 1.month).strftime(%Y)"/
 26   }
 27 }
 28 ### Unable to combine these for the %B and %Y despite several tries mdd 9/13/2015
 29 /Date.*new.*month/ {
 30   s/"//g
 31   s/%B/"%B"/
 32   s/%Y/"%Y"/
 33 }
 34 /choose_submodel_text/ {
 35   s/" \] =/\n    /
 36 }
 37 /email.*albert.*random/ {
 38   s/("albert.*gmail\.com")/Faker::Internet.email/
 39 }
 40 ' Variables/user-extensions.js | awk '
 41 ### ADD Header and footer
 42 BEGIN { print "# page object methods"; print "module PageObject # Variable values" }
 43       { print }
 44 END { print "end" } '> rspec_conversions/new_page_object_methods.rb
 45 rubocop -a rspec_conversions/new_page_object_methods.rb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> s/"value=.*\+1)/"(Date.new + 1.month).strftime(%B)"/
>           ^^^
> ```

You have the `*` zero-or-more repetition operator followed by `\+`. The meaning of `\+` depends on the version of sed. It might match `+` or `\+`, or it might be the one-or-more repetition operator. GNU sed treats `\+` as the one-or-more repetition operator, except in a context where it wouldn't make sense¹, such as here, following another repetition operator. I think that OSX sed treats `\+` as the one-or-more repetition operator, and complains here because two consecutive repetition operators doesn't make sense.

In sed, to match `+`, write `+`.

¹  <sub>Well, it would make sense, but all sequences of repetition operators except `{…}` can be collapsed to a single one, so most regexp engines treat them specially.</sub>