# RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Tags: sed

I'm getting this error

> RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

On FreeBSD sed, using csh.

Command is:

```
sed -rn 's/.*?VIEW ([^\s]+?) (AS .*?)\s([^\s]+?)\s([^\s]+?)/DROP VIEW \1;\nCREATE VIEW \1 \2;/p'
```

I've seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229476/getting-re-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-on-osx-sed) but I don't have any `*+`s, but I do have some `*?`s, but that's supposed to mean non-greedy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"I do have some *?s, but that's supposed to mean non-greedy."_  In perl, yes, but not in sed.

Comment: @John1024 No flavours of `sed` support that? I lifted that regex from somewhere else, weird that someone would post that without trying it at least once.

Comment: No variant of `sed` that I know about does that.  Can you provide a link to your source?

Comment: "super sed" aka [ssed](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/ssed/) supports perl regular expressions with the `-R` or `--regexp-perl` options.   `ssed` is forked from GNU `sed`.

Comment: @John1024 This is where I got it from: http://blog.novoj.net/2014/05/16/recreate-mysql-views-without-definer-one-liner-solution-linux/

Comment: OK.  That blog post appears to be in error.  As you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed), standard `sed` does not do non-greedy matches.  That includes the GNU, BSD, and POSIX variants.  One solution might be to use @cas's suggestion of `ssed`.  Alternatively, you might open a question documenting your input and desired output for that `sed` command and I bet that there will be good solutions using standard sed and its usual greedy regexes.

Comment: @John1024 Cool, thanks for your help. I'm not even sure those expressions need to be non-greedy; I'll play around with it a bit and then ask if I need more help. You can post what you said here as an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was already mentioned in the comments to the question, but to make the answer more explicit:

> Non-greedy matching is not available in sed, using either standard or extended regex mode.

If you know the character that should terminate the match, you can use the following technique, as found here: https://0x2a.at/blog/2008/07/sed--non-greedy-matching/

Greedy matching:

```
$ echo "<b>foo</b>bar" | sed 's/<.*>//g'
bar
```

Non-greedy matching:

```
$ echo "<b>foo</b>bar" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
foobar
```