# Use sed, awk, or vim to delete everything in a line that starts with + except for the +

Tags: awk, sed, vim

I have a fastq file where I must delete everything in certain lines except for the first character. Here is an example:

```
@A202BNABXX:2:1:4523:2219/1
GGCCGAATTCACCGATAAAATACACAGACGGTAAATGTTCCCACTAGGTTCACCTATGAGTCCGCTATGCCCGCCGGCATTTCAATTTCT
+ERR706845.1.1 A202BNABXX:2:1:4523:2219 length=90
@A202BNABXX:2:1:4715:2246/1
CTGAGGACTGCATGACATGGACTGATGCACTCTATAATCATTTTAATGCAATTGTCACTATTCATGAAATTGTGTAACTTACTAAATAGT
+ERR706845.2.1 A202BNABXX:2:1:4715:2246 length=90
```

The plus is at the beginning of the line in the fastq file. For every line that starts with the `+` symbol, I need to delete everything after it. Then I need to rewrite the output to a new file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/^(\+).*/\1/' input_file > new_file
$ cat new_file
@A202BNABXX:2:1:4523:2219/1
GGCCGAATTCACCGATAAAATACACAGACGGTAAATGTTCCCACTAGGTTCACCTATGAGTCCGCTATGCCCGCCGGCATTTCAATTTCT

+

@A202BNABXX:2:1:4715:2246/1
CTGAGGACTGCATGACATGGACTGATGCACTCTATAATCATTTTAATGCAATTGTCACTATTCATGAAATTGTGTAACTTACTAAATAGT

+
```

Comment: Or just `sed 's/^+.*/+/'` shorter and more portable.

Comment: Or `sed '/^+/c+'` with GNU `sed`.

Comment: Hello! So the first sed command listed worked! The only problem is that some of my lines that I do not want to delete also start with a +. The lines that I for sure want to delete all start with "+ERR706845". Is there a way to manipulate the sed command so it only deletes everything except the + character on those lines? Thanks!

Comment: @Lydia Try `sed -E '/+ERR706845/s/^(\+).*/\1/'`

Comment: Hello @HatLess this is the error I got from running this: sed -E '/+ERR706845/s/^(\+).*/\1/' ERR351507_pass_1.fastq  > TR01_R1_001.fastq
sed: 1: "/+ERR706845/s/^(\+).*/\1/": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid  thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: I found this post: [link] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229476/getting-re-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-on-osx-sed but I don't know how exactly how to fix this problem for my mac

Comment: @Lydia Sorry, I did not test it, the + needs to be escaped. `sed -E '/\+ERR706845/s/^(\+).*/\1/'`

Comment: @HatLess thank you so much it worked! I appreciate your help and explanation :)

Comment: @HatLess thank you so much it worked! I appreciate your help and explanation :)

Comment: You're only having to escape `+` because you're using `-E`. If you don't add `-E` then you don't need to add the ```\``` bfore the `+` either.